# How to change the values of an array?

Tags: c

I am making a game and have thus far generated a random board. I would like to know how i would be able to print an asterisk after each of the elements on the board as i make my way from one element of the board to the other. I would also like to know if there is a way to print out an "&" at the element i have gone to. So the randomly generated board automatically gets updated with the current position and the previously visited elements.

Comment: You can print an asterisk with `puts("*")`. If you need more details, you'll need to give more details.

Comment: How about posting some actual code and explaining what expected & how it behaves?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of the board position and update the array based on your new position.

I.e. You could start at position 1 and move 5 places you would then be at position 6.

Store the value 6 in a variable, such as userPosition: userPosition = 6;

You could update your array directly by using: boardPosition[userPosition] = '*';

Or you could iterate through the entire array and add a * for position 6 and all positions prior to that.

```
int index;
for (index = 0; index <= userPosition; index++) {
    boardPosition[index] = '*';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying positively.

Comment: The Problem that i am having is that the board is generated randomly so i cant simply generate a code for moving from one place to the other or in other words i am not sure if it is possible to come up with a definitive solution to the board.